# difference between the two constructor calls

Tags: java, class, constructor, call

### First `queue` class

```
class queue
{
    private char q[];
    queue(int size)              //constructor 1
    {
        q=new char[size];
    }
    queue(char array[])          //constructor 2
    {
        this(array.length);      //call to constructor 1
    }
}
```

### Second `queue` class

```
class queue
{
    private char q[];
    queue(int size)              //constructor 1
    {
        q=new char[size];
    }
    queue(char array[])          //constructor 2
    {
        queue(array.length);      //call to constructor 1
    }
}
```

In the First `queue` class, `call to constructor 1` works fine,

But in the Second `queue` class, `call to constructor 1` shows error.

What is the difference between the above two contstructor calls?

*(Please don't pay attention to the relevance of the code)*

Comment: Classes should start with a capital letter, also constructors. If you don't use the Java coding conventions, you will confuse every other programmer reading your code.

Comment: Do we need to guess what the error is that is shown? You should add it to your question - it's relevant information that you need to share.

Comment: **Side note**: before diving further into the java language, I would recommend to study the java naming conventions (it doesnt make much sense to start with a personal "style", to then later realize "oh, i should do things differently) - although, it is just that class names should start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to call a constructor in a class from another constructor in the same class in Java is to use `this`. The call `queue(array.length);` is illegal in Java. The compiler will look for a method named `queue` that takes an int parameter and since such a method is not present, you get a compilation error.